# Herokuapp can't deploy, but works perfectly on localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have a problem with my first chat app. When I run on the localhost, it works perfectly. But, when i deploy it to the Herokuapp, it was an error:
[Error Herokuapp Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdvya.png)

Here is my script: [app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhKgQ.png)

```
var express = require('express')
var http = require('http')
var socketio = require('socket.io')

var app = express()
var http = http.createServer(app)
var io = socketio(http)

var path = require('path')
var config = {
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views/index.html"))
})

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    io.emit('join')
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        io.emit('leave')
    })
    socket.on('chat message', function(x) {
        io.emit('post message', x)
    })
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))

http.listen(config.port)
```

Full file structure: [File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEaly.png)

btw here is the error message i cannot understand:

```
...
2020-11-07T03:29:47.092238+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
2020-11-07T03:29:47.092284+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-11-07T03:29:47.092285+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-11-07T03:29:47.092285+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-11-07T03:29:47.092286+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
...
```

Comment: Have you commited your `package.json` and `package-lock.json`?

Comment: Please share package.json and procfile

Comment: This error means you are not using `npm install` in your package.json `start`. Can you show us your package.json?

Comment: you probably have installed express globally

Answer (score 0):

If you run heroku logs on your terminal, do you get a mongoose openuri() error? If so, you’ll have to set your config vars in your app’s settings on heroku for your environment variables like PORT, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the express module is included in your package.json file. That should fix it